# Unable to dynamically load a control into a SplitContainer panel

Tags: vb.net, winforms, custom-controls

I have placed a `SplitContainer` control onto a form.  I have a custom control inside `panel 1`. This custom control is the container for another user-control.

There is a `TreeView` control inside this user-control.  I am trying to load another user-control onto panel 2 upon  selection of a node in the tree view. But its not getting loaded. Am i missing something?

The code for loading the control is given below:

```
Dim ucImportExcel1 As New ucImportExcel()
frmMain.SplitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(ucImportExcel1)
ucImportExcel1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
```

An addition to the above: In the same `treeview` selection event

For the code below it sets the form text:

```
me.parentform.text = "Sample Text 1"
```

Whereas if use this code, nothing happens:

```
frmmain.text = "Sample Text 2"
```

Comment: Try setting `ucImportExcel1.Visible = True`.  Does it work with some other standard control, such as a `Button`?

Comment: The code as written works fine for a standard control (I used a button), so I'm guessing it has something to do with your userControl

Comment: In your ucImportExcel, are you setting anything in the New Sub?

Comment: I tried .visible but still the same. When I use this code   MsgBox(frmMain.SplitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Item(0).Name), it gives me the name of the usercontrol as well. So it means, its added to the control but not displayed.

Comment: Are the second user control (inside the first) and the treeview added?

Comment: Yes they are added and I can fire the treeview afterselect event.

Comment: The second user control ( I am trying to load another user-control onto panel 2 ) what is it?

Comment: The second usercontrol (ucImportExcel1) is a usercontrol containing a datagrid.This is what i have in the New sub:  Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        MsgBox("user control initialised")
    End Sub

Comment: Are you filling the user control with data? Maybe you don't , so it doesn't shows rows and columns

Answer (score 0):

When referred by a `Directcast`, it solved the problem:

```
DirectCast(Me.ParentForm.Controls.Item("SplitContainer1"), System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer).Panel2.Controls.Add(ucImportExcel1)
```